# math inside title in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I am writing a script to emulate a mathematica notebook with tcolorbox in latex.

it seems to be perfectly ok as long as I do not have an equal sign in the title. If I do, it breaks

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=$a=b$,title filled]
\(a=5\)
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: You have 0% accepted answers for your questions. Would you consider accepting some of the answers you got if they solved your problems? It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need brackets:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title={$a=b$},title filled]
\(a=5\)
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]